# Webpack on the backend: missing exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to use webpack on the backend to transpile this code (called `sub.js`):

```
export const foo1 = () => {
  console.log("I'm foo1");
};

console.log('loaded');
```

I can compile it and then import it fine. On import (`require`) I see the 'loaded', but the imported object is empty and in particular has no function `foo1`.

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: `./sub.js`,
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        plugins: [
          '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
        ]
      },
    }],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'backend.js'
  },
  mode: 'production',
};
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sub",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/backend.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  }
}
```

I test using:

```
> npx webpack && node --eval "r = require('./dist/backend.js'); console.log(r);"
asset backend.js 45 bytes [emitted] [minimized] (name: main)
runtime modules 396 bytes 2 modules
./sub.js 204 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.65.0 compiled successfully in 250 ms
loaded
{}
```

I was expecting to see:

```
loaded
{foo1: [Function]}
```

or similar.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `export` with `import`, instead of `require`?

Comment: no, that doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. Apparently you need to explicitly declare exported libraries in the output. Now that I've added this:

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'backend.js',
    library: {
        type: 'commonjs-module',
    },
  },
```

I get:

```
> npx webpack && node --eval "r = require('./dist/backend.js'); console.log(r);"
asset backend.js 192 bytes [emitted] [minimized] (name: main)
./sub.js 323 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.65.0 compiled successfully in 275 ms
loaded
{ foo1: [Function] }
```

as expected.

For reference https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary.

Comment: This is really unintuitive as export clearly states that you want to expose your object. Thank you for adding an answer to your question. (I lost 2 days looking for a solution)